# MDL card positioning within HTML

Tags: html, css, material-design, css-position, material-design-lite

I am relatively new to MDL and I am trying to understand how to position cards within or next to a piece of text I have. I am very close but I have tried lots of different ways and I don't seem to be getting the outcome I am looking for.

I would like the text to be on the left (which I am happy with at the moment where it is positioned) and two wide MDL cards on the right one on top of the other, in line with the text.

So far I have:

```
    <body>
        <div class="header">

                <a class="logo" target="_blank"><img src=".\images\logo.png" border="0" alt="logo" width="90"></a>
                <div class="header-left">
                  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                  <a href="wall.html">Wall</a>
                  <a class="active" href="shop.html">Shop</a>
                  <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                  <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
            <div class="header-right">
                  <a class="active" href="http://instagram.com/woolybox" target="_blank"><img src=".\images\instagram.png" border="0" alt="instagram"img width="20" height="20"></a>
                  <a href="http://twitter.com/wooly_box" target="_blank"><img src=".\images\twitter.png" border="0" alt="twitter" img width="20" height="20"></a>
                </div>
                </div>
<p>
<table>
  <div class="boxed-1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sed feugiat lectus. Phasellus maximus, ex nec bibendum volutpat, justo erat pellentesque massa, vel malesuada sem lectus tincidunt orci. Aenean eleifend est sit amet dapibus ullamcorper. Nam ornare finibus ex vitae interdum. Sed quis purus eros. Sed ut porttitor dolor, eget ultrices justo. Sed eu leo porta, mattis libero eu, sagittis metus. Vivamus nec lobortis nisi. Suspendisse posuere enim arcu, at interdum dui congue vitae. Aliquam vestibulum accumsan magna. Vivamus a arcu nunc. Cras euismod lacinia augue sed elementum. Phasellus dignissim semper mi at sollicitudin. Vivamus maximus semper nulla. Donec luctus, dolor non viverra aliquam, enim arcu imperdiet sem, et pretium dui ante ac lectus.
    </div></table>
<p>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="float-right">
        <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <div class="mdl-card__title">
              <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Welcome</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
              <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                Get Started
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__menu">
              <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                <i class="material-icons">share</i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <p>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="float-right">
              <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
                  <div class="mdl-card__title">
                    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Welcome</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
                  </div>
                  <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                    <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                      Get Started
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mdl-card__menu">
                    <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                      <i class="material-icons">share</i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    <p>



    <footer class="mdl-mega-footer">
        <div class="mdl-mega-footer__middle-section">

          <div class="mdl-mega-footer__drop-down-section">
            <input class="mdl-mega-footer__heading-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked>
            <h1 class="mdl-mega-footer__heading">woolyBox ltd.</h1>
            <ul class="mdl-mega-footer__link-list">
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="mdl-mega-footer__bottom-section">
          <ul class="mdl-mega-footer__link-list">
            <li><a href="#">Privacy & Terms</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </p></div>

</body>
```

and CSS:

```
html, body { 
  height: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

body {
  background: #fafafa;
  position: relative;
}

table { 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #f4d442;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

td { 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}



.header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }


  .header a {
    float: left;
    color: grey;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 18px; 
    line-height: 25px;

  }


  .header a.logo {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }


  .header a:hover {
    color: black;
  }


  .header a.active {
    color: #f4d442;
  }


  .header-right {
    float: right;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .header a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }

  .header-right {
      float: none;
    }
  }


.content {
  padding: 16px;
}


  .boxed{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 60vh;
    box-align: left;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 5%;
    background-color:  #fff;
    margin: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%; 
  }

/* .image {

} */

.boxed-1 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top: 10%;
  background-color:  #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 5%; 
  margin-right: 80%;
}



  .container-wrapper{text-align:center;}

  .container-1,
  .container-2,
  .container-3{width:475px; height:400px; display:inline-block; margin-left:10px; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;}

  .container-1{background:grey; margin-left:0;}
  .container-2{background:grey;}
  .container-3{background:grey;}


  @media all and (max-width: 650px) {
      .container-1{
        width:100%; 
        display:block; 
        margin:0;
      }

      .container-2{
        width:100%; 
        display:block; 
        margin:0;
      }
      .container-3{
        width:100%;
        display:block; 
        margin:0;
      }
  }

  .card-img-top {
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .card {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .card-text {
  color: grey;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 16px; 
  line-height: 25px;

  }
  .demo-card-square.mdl-card {
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    float: left;
    margin: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .demo-card-square.mdl-card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  }

  .demo-card-square > .mdl-card__title {
    color: #fff;
    background: #03a9f4;
  }

  .demo-card-square > .mdl-card__accent {
    background: #ff9800;
  }

 .demo-card-wide.mdl-card {
  width: 100%;

}
.demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__title {
  color: #fff;
  height: 176px;
  background: url('../assets/demos/welcome_card.jpg') center / cover;
}
.demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__menu {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Is anyone able to point me in the correct direction as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: In the future, try to trim down the code you provide to just the minimum needed to show the issue you are trying to resolve. You will get more help (and quicker) since it saves us from having to scan through the irrelevant stuff. No worries though... look into css `display: flex` and `display: grid` as a starting point to help you work through layout stuff beyond the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to get the layout you are looking for. A simple one for what you are after is to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). Below is a minimal example of a [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/) layout with a header, main content, and a footer that includes the text and card positioning you describe.

You will see that the `main` html element is set to `display: flex`, and `align-items: center` which displays its child elements side by side and vertically aligned in the middle (you can experiment with different `align-items` options if you are looking for some other vertical alignment). The cards are wrapped in a `div` so that they are displayed stacked alongside the text (rather than both side by side).

```css
.mdl-layout__content main {
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.mdl-card {
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Material Design Lite layout example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">

      <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Logo</span>
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <nav class="mdl-navigation">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div class="mdl-layout__content">

        <main>

          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sed feugiat lectus. Phasellus maximus, ex nec bibendum volutpat, justo erat pellentesque massa, vel malesuada sem lectus tincidunt orci. Aenean eleifend est sit amet dapibus ullamcorper.
            Nam ornare finibus ex vitae interdum. Sed quis purus eros. Sed ut porttitor dolor, eget ultrices justo. Sed eu leo porta, mattis libero eu, sagittis metus. Vivamus nec lobortis nisi. Suspendisse posuere enim arcu, at interdum dui congue vitae.
            Aliquam vestibulum accumsan magna. Vivamus a arcu nunc. Cras euismod lacinia augue sed elementum. Phasellus dignissim semper mi at sollicitudin. Vivamus maximus semper nulla. Donec luctus, dolor non viverra aliquam, enim arcu imperdiet sem,
            et pretium dui ante ac lectus.
          </div>

          <div class="cards">

            <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
              <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Welcome</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      Get Started
    </a>
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__menu">
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      <i class="material-icons">share</i>
    </button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
              <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Welcome</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      Get Started
    </a>
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__menu">
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      <i class="material-icons">share</i>
    </button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- close cards -->

        </main>

        <footer class="mdl-mini-footer">
          <div class="mdl-mini-footer__left-section">
            <div class="mdl-logo">Title</div>
            <ul class="mdl-mini-footer__link-list">
              <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Privacy & Terms</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </footer>

      </div>
      <!-- close mdl-layout__content -->

    </div>
    <!-- close mdl-layout -->

    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

In your own html, it looks like you are using `p` tags as breaks in some places without closing the tag (there is a `br` tag that is more appropriate for what you intend, but I would recommend against this as you can get what you are looking for by setting appropriate `margin` and/or `padding` values in your css). You also forgot to close your `footer` tag. You can use a [html validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to help you clean up syntax issues like these.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, this didn't work within my code, I will have another look through it later but there seemed to be a huge white gap in between elements and the text was squashed to the far left and vice versa for the cards. but they did align correctly so I'll have a coffee and make some sense of it!

Comment: If you are trying to embed some of the html and css from the answer without too much change to the code you posted in your question, you will need to clean up the conflicting css (especially where you are using `float`) and make sure that there aren't unintended consequences from your html structure (like wrapping everything in your `div.header`).